# Group by many to many table

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have the following table:

```
performance
  --id
  --color
  --installs
  --date

performance_groups
  --id
  --performance_id
  --group_id
```

I would like to have an SQL something like this:

```
 SELECT color, targeting_id, SUM(installs) as installs
 FROM performance, performance_groups
GROUP BY color, group_id
```

But I would like the grouping to be done for all groups.

For example:

```
performance
id     color     installs   date
1      Blue      5          2017-07-05
2      Red       10         2017-07-04
3      Blue      10         2017-07-04
4      Blue      10         2017-07-05

performance_groups
id   performance_id   group_id
1    1                1
2    1                2
3    2                3
4    3                1
5    3                2
6    4                1
7    4                3
```

I would like to get results like this:

```
color group_ids installs
Blue  1,2     15
Red   3       10
Blue  1,3     10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Gordon and Radium I got an inspiration to my answer.

The final solution is:

```
with pg as(
    select performance_id, array_agg(distinct group_id) as groups from performance_groups
    group by performance_id
) 
select groups, sum(installs) from performance join pg 
on pg.performance_id = performance.id
group by groups
```

See working [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/38d3d/3)

Answer (score 3):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Your query would then seem to be a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select p.color, string_agg(pg.group_id) as groups, 
       sum(installs) as installs
from performance p join
     performance_groups pg
     on pg.performance_id = p.id
group by color;
```

Comment: Thanks. I am checking it - can you please elaborate wha tis the difference between join and comma?

Comment: `JOIN` is the correct syntax.  Commas are archaic syntax that has been out-of-date for over two decades.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_agg` and do not forget about the distinct. The join may produce duplicates.

```
select p.color, array_agg(distinct pg.group_id) as groups, 
       sum(distinct installs) as installs
from performance p 
join performance_groups pg
     on pg.performance_id = p.id
group by color;
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/26092/5)

Comment: sounds like the right answer. will check more and upate

Answer (score 0):

```
We are using STUFF,XML PATH and GROUP BY in SQL 2008.
```

Code :

```
    select f.color,
    (SELECT STUFF(( SELECT ',' + convert(varchar(5),j.group_id) 
    FROM (select distinct g.group_id from performance_groups g 
    where g.performance_id in (select id from performance where color= 
    f.color)) j FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, 
    '')) as group_ids,
    SUM(f.installs) installs
    from performance f group by color
```

OUTPUT :

```
color   group_ids   installs
Blue    1,2         15
Red     3           10
```

Comment: but I am using postgres sql - how does it help?